# Accessing docker-compose containers via ipv6 from the outside of the docker host

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6, docker-compose, radvd

I have the following (simplified) `docker(-compose)` setup and would like access the nginx container from the laptop. A ping from the laptop to the `docker-compose` gateway (`fd..2222.0.0.1/80`) works fine but to `fd..2222.0.0.2/80` doesnt work.

[image]

I already tried to advertise a route via `radvd` (running on the Server):

```
interface wlp1s0 {
    IgnoreIfMissing on;
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 600;

    route fddd::2222:0:0:0/80 {
        AdvRouteLifetime 900;
        AdvRoutePreference low;
    };
};
```

The route gets added to the laptop:

```
$ ip -6 -br r
...
fddd::2222:0:0:0/80 via fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev wlan0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 684sec pref low
...
```

but theres still no ping getting through. Could you help me getting this to work?

```
$ ip -6 -br a   # Server
lo               UNKNOWN        ::1/128
wlp1s0           UP             ... fddd::2c2:c6ff:febd:862a/64 ...
docker0          DOWN           fddd::1111:0:0:1/80 fe80::xxxx/64 fe80::1/64
br-ae6409628391  UP             fddd::2222:0:0:1/80 fe80::xxxx/64 fe80::1/64
```

Comment: does IPv4 ping work?

Comment: Ping from where to where? Laptop --ipv4--> nginx will not work, since DC implements NAT. Laptop --ipv4--> Server works fine as well as `curl Server:8080` since nginx does have the port exposed to the host via `-p 8080:80`.

Comment: I must misunderstand your setup ... so, you can't ping using ipv6, but there's no similar router for ipv4?

Comment: Well yes. But thats not extraordinary. IPv6 and 4 do not have to have the same connectivity. From the Laptop I cant ping4 nginx anyway since its NATed by Docker(-Compose). But IPv4 is out of question here. Why are you asking?

Comment: to see if there's ANY connectivity at all

Comment: Yes, there is. Outgoing comm. from nginx to e.g. google works fine (thought all layers, 4 and 6).

Comment: @JaromandaX problem still persist. Any ideas?